# Discrete Markov Process generator

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

`Addlisttoone = Function[{n, k}, m = Table[Table[ RandomInteger[{0, 4}], {i, n}], {j, k}]; sm = Table[Total[m[[i]]], {i, k}]; M = Table[Table[m[[i, j]]/sm[[i]], {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, k}]];`

The above code gives as result a matrix with each row adds up to one.
So the idea is to create a transition matrix generator in order to use it with the `Graph[DiscreteMarkovProcess[]]`.

Although the function works as planned, I cannot use it with the `Graph[DiscreteMarkovProcess[]]`  function.

As output I have the following:
{{1/7, 1/7, 3/7, 2/7}, {0, 0, 2/3, 1/3}, {2/13, 4/13, 3/13, 4/13}, {1/
3, 1/4, 1/3, 1/12}, {1/6, 1/2, 1/6, 1/6}, {2/11, 1/11, 4/11, 4/11}}

When I try to substitute the above at an example from [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteMarkovProcess.html):

`proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[ 1, {{1/2, 1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {1/3, 2/3, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/3, 2/3, 0,  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}}]; Graph[proc]`

Now when I try with my generated data nothing happens:

`Graph[DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, Addlisttoone[4, 6]]]`
or
`Graph[DiscreteMarkovProcess[1,{{1/7, 1/7, 3/7, 2/7}, {0, 0, 2/3, 1/3}, {2/13, 4/13, 3/13, 4/13}, {1/ 3, 1/4, 1/3, 1/12}, {1/6, 1/2, 1/6, 1/6}, {2/11, 1/11, 4/11, 4/11}}]`

The function is not processed.

Where did I do something wrong? I read somewhere here about absorbing states. If this is the case, can some one help?

Comment: The matrix needs to be square. Yours is 4 by 6.

Comment: Unbelievable, such a rookie mistake. Thanks